# Acknowledgement from Consumer in ActiveMQ

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am writing a Java application using ActiveMQ. I have a Producer Class (which takes user input)  and a Consumer Class with a listener, so that as soon as messages arrive, Message Listener executes the onMessage(msg) function. 
My question, though, is when does a consumer sends back the acknowledgement to the broker, so that the msg is de-queued from the broker? Is it after completing the actions written in the onMessage(msg) function or is it just when the onMessage(msg) function is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the normal case the ack is sent after the onMessage completes since it needs to handle the case of onMessage throwing an exception.

Comment: Yup.. I just checked after asking to wait in the onMessage() function and the acknowledgement was not sent.. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Depends how it's configured, and in part on how you [use transactions](http://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-transactions.html).

Are you using a message-driven bean? In that case, i believe the acknowledgement will be sent when the transaction is successfully committed. See the [specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr220/index.html) (specifically the 'ejbcore' version), section *5.4.14 Message Acknowledgment for JMS Message-Driven Beans*, which says:

> Message acknowledgment is automatically handled by the container. If the message-driven bean uses container-managed transaction demarcation, message acknowledgment is handled automatically as a part ofthe transaction commit.

It goes on to say:

> If bean-managed transaction demarcation is used, the message receipt cannot be part of the bean-managed transaction, and, in this case, the receipt is acknowledged by the container. If bean-managed transaction demarcation is used, the Bean Provider can indicate whether JMS `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` semantics or `DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` semantics should apply by using the `activationConfig` element of the `MessageDriven` annotation or by using the `activation-config-property` deployment descriptor element.

But since you really shouldn't be using bean-managed transactions, that is hopefully irrelevant.