# ActiveMQ with Spring Boot. Messages persistance is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic, jmstemplate

I want to use ActiveMQ within Spring Boot app as embedded server. To setup ActiveMQ I used following tutorial: [Spring Boot. Messaging with JMS.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/#initial) My app will be the broker and the consumer. There are multiple threads creating messages like this:

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;
.......
MessageCreator messageCreator = session -> session.createObjectMessage(transactionNotificationData);
                        jmsTemplate.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                        jmsTemplate.send(QUEUE, messageCreator);
```

I have another class with following method:

```
@JmsListener(destination = QUEUE)
public void receive(Message message) throws IOException {
    brokerService.getPersistenceAdapter();
    try {
        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
            NotificationData notification = (NotificationData) objMessage.getObject();
            LOG.info("Received <" + notification.notification + ">");
            ...... do some stuff ........
//            message.acknowledge();
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

During the tests I can see the messages are produced and consumed. 
As you can see `message.acknowledge()` is commented. So I expect the message will be redelivered after rerun of my app. However it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 2):

Message Acknowledgement is automatically handled by the container and it executes after the onMessage() is successfully executed,(receive() in your case),

so even when you comment `message.acknowledge();` , container on its own sends the acknowledgement

you can have a look at following link for more reference

- [Acknowledgement from Consumer in ActiveMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9532948/acknowledgement-from-consumer-in-activemq)

Hope this helps!

Good luck!

Comment: @Loco did this answer your question?